# Do exterior pocket doors exist?

Tags: doors, pocket-door

Is there such a thing as a pocket door (with seal) for 4" exterior walls? We want to replace our sliding glass doors.

Comment: I haven't yet seen pocket doors that have anything like a real seal. I'd suggest going to a normal swinging door or double door unless you have space constraints on both sides which would prevent that.

Comment: A swinging door would be awkward in our situation, and sliding glass doors have more glass than we prefer.  The concept of a pocket door seemed ideal, but for the seal issue.

Comment: Have a look at garage door seals, available at your local home center. You can generally buy a piece of "trim" that is integrated with a seal of some kind. If your pocket door is shaped right, with a seal-friendly edge, there's no reason you shouldn't be able to get garage-door level (read: not very good, actually) performance. If you have a storm door or some other 2nd layer of protection, it might be okay depending on where you live (Florida yes, Canada no).

Comment: If the problem is just too much glass, then covering the glass might be easier and add a bit more insulation value.  4 inch walls will not have any space for insulation, so be about the same/a bit worst than well sealed glass.

Comment: Why the pocket door constraint? Are solid sliding doors sufficient? I guess the fixed panel would look pretty goofy. Is it easy for you to source and install siding over the pocket's area, though?

Comment: Just replacing -- or putting a facing on -- the glass panel is an interesting thought... Is the concern insulating or privacy? Privacy can be addressed with cling films, either frosted or mock-stained-glass; I've done that with other windows. Or with curtains, which can also help insulate somewhat

Comment: Location/weather conditions are important to know.  4 inch walls do not leave space for the good stuff like insulation.

Comment: The reason for not wanting to use sliding doors has to do with personal preference.  We do want some glass in the door, but since the space can't accommodate a swing door we may need to go back to the sliding door option.  Was hoping there might be a ready-made product available that includes good air-seal features.  We definitely don't want to spend time rigging up an unconventional pocket door scenario.

Comment: If you can't accommodate *a* swing door, have you considered French doors?  Perhaps you can accommodate two narrow swinging doors easier than a single large swinging door?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for residential applications. The implications for air, water, and pest intrusion, as well as security and energy efficiency, make them impractical.

I suggest a new sliding patio door with either translucent film or a solid paper to close off the glass. You may also be able to find doors with little or no glass from the factory.

Answer (score 2):

This may be regional, so it may not be possible in your area.

In Florida there are some builders that will install a "stackable" slider where all the panels slide against an outside wall.  That wall can be built with a "Cover" over the stack of door panels giving the appearance of the doors going into a "pocket".

There is not a particular kit or manufacturer for this. It is something done by a custom builder. (The doors and track and frame is from a supplier. The "Pocket" is custom construction.)

This type of exterior door was only advised to be built when the doors would be totally under cover of a hard roof.  It was not good for rain and other outdoor debris, (leaves, grass clippings etc.) to be allowed to get in the pocket. Therefore a screened area was necessary as well.

As you can surmise, these were only installed on new construction.